# C++ use '&' to create a pointer to member

Tags: c++

```
bool check(char* test) {
string str(test);

string blacklist[] = {"str1", "str2", "test", "str3"};

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(blacklist); i++) {
    if (str.find(blacklist[i]) != std::string::npos) {
        clog << blacklist[i].c_str << endl;
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
}
```

For what reason this throws an error
 "use '&' to create a pointer to member"

```
int main()
{
char *test = "test";

if (check(test)) {
    clog << "Found " << test << endl;
}
```

and this is the main function where i call the method from.

Comment: `blacklist[i].c_str` -> `blacklist[i].c_str()`.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo

Comment: Also, `sizeof(blacklist)` is bigger than you think it is.